# Testing a ViewPager and TabPageIndicator with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I can't seem to find any examples on using Espresso to test a ViewPager + TabPageIndicator setup. My application has a custom TabPageIndicator which on selection of a Tab will update the corresponding ViewPager page. Any direction on this would be helpful!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can click on a part of your TabPageIndicator that takes you to a respective tab in the ViewPager. If that's the case, do your tab indicators have any unique parts to them? (e.g. id, text, tag)

Comment: Currently they only have a unique color. Would adding unique ids and using the id be the way to go here?

Comment: You could. Being a tab page indicator, I would think that tags would probably be a more appropriate solution than ids. You can take a look at the tag matching options at [Espresso's Java Doc](http://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git-history/017131c0f6edd605e19188ccf2ea61f76b108d83/docs/javadocs/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withTagKey(int)).

Comment: Any luck writing this code?  I am curious too...